# Fuzzy Transform cancels after execute phase begins "SSIS package finished: Canceled"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, fuzzy-search

I have a basic fuzzy transform that pulls data from a `OLE DB` source (connected to `sql server 2008 r2`), references against another table in the same SQL db that holds the source then is split into multiple columns. The package successfully pulls from the source but after building the match index, warming caches, and finishing pre-execute phase the package immediately stops and says:

> SSIS package "Product.dtsx" finished: Canceled.
>   The program '[3796] Product.dtsx: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0)."

I have no idea as to why it cancels, no other information is provided. I have triple checked my drivers, my project 64runtime is set to true, I have scoured the Internet for an answer to this to no avail. The `.tmp` file dumped in SQLserver's errorlog folder doesn't seem to provide any additional information either. Could anyone shed any light on this situation?

- Windows 7 ent x64 based
- Intel i5-3320m 4gb ram
- Visual Studio 2008 9.0.30729.4462 QFE
- .NET Framework 3.5 SP1